# How to correctly write jQuery toggle button that can work individualy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create simple script which toggles buttons that can be placed *anywhere* on the page and work *individualy* no matter how the structure is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.togBtn').each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $('.togItem').hide();
        } else {
          $('.togItem').show();
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="togBtn" id="togBtn-1">
    <button>But 1</button>
    <div class="togItem" id="togItem-1">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-2">But 2</button>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-3">But 3</button>
  <div class="togItem" id="togBtn-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="togItem" id="togBtn-3">Item 3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code?

Comment: The button seems doesn't work..

Comment: Get the id of the button (or the closest parent with a `togBtn-x` id), replace `togBtn` with `togItem` and use it as selector.

Comment: If something is not working, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I try to change it with `$(.togItem).next()` but it only works for the last item ('item 3')

Comment: @Andreas can you please giveme an example to write with `togBtn-x` id?

Comment: You may want to look into [jQuery's tutorial on creating plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several issues in your code. Firstly a `click` handler function cannot have an `else` block. Secondly you try to hide/show *all* `.togItem` elements instead of the one related to the clicked button.

To approach this more logically, group the button and the content to be shown together. Then you can use DOM traversal to find the related item when the button is clicked. In the example below I made both of them children of a `div` and used `next()` to relate them. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.togBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.togItem').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="togBtnContainer">
    <button class="togBtn">But 1</button>
    <div class="togItem">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="togBtnContainer">
    <button class="togBtn">But 2</button>
    <div class="togItem">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="togBtnContainer">
    <button class="togBtn">But 3</button>
    <div class="togItem">Item 3</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If the HTML is spread out and the related elements are not siblings then you can instead use `data` attributes to relate them, like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.togBtn').click(function() {
    var targetSelector = $(this).data('target');
    $(targetSelector).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="togBtn" id="togBtn-1" data-target="#togItem-1">
    <button>But 1</button>
    <div class="togItem" id="togItem-1">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-2" data-target="#togItem-2">But 2</button>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-3" data-target="#togItem-3">But 3</button>
  <div class="togItem" id="togItem-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="togItem" id="togItem-3">Item 3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @RedFrog it should do, as you can see in the example above.

Comment: @Andreas just realised what you meant! I read the HTML wrong in the question :)

Comment: You need both. `data-target` on the element which is clicked, and a matching `id` on the element to toggle

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the button (or its parent element if the button itself doesn't have one) with the help of [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and the ["attribute starts with" selector (`^=`)](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
var togBtnId = $(this).closest('[id^="togBtn-"]').attr("id");
```

Then just replace `togBtn` with `togItem` to get the id of the related item and use this as the selector for [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle):

```
$("#" + togBtnId.replace("togBtn", "togItem")).toggle();
```

Example:

```js
$(".togBtn").on("click", function() {
  var togBtnId = $(this)
                   .closest('[id^="togBtn-"]')  // .closest() because "But 1" has no id itself but its parent
                   .attr("id");
  
  if (togBtnId) {
    $("#" + togBtnId.replace("togBtn", "togItem")).toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="togBtn" id="togBtn-1">
    <button>But 1</button>
    <div class="togItem" id="togItem-1">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-2">But 2</button>
  <button class="togBtn" id="togBtn-3">But 3</button>
  <div class="togItem" id="togItem-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="togItem" id="togItem-3">Item 3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)