# Running a jQuery function on multiple divs (getting background image from img tag and applying it as section background using CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, function

I am trying to get the image src of each section and apply it to the section with CSS as the background-image property using jQuery. The reason I need to get the image URL which the CMS loads and add it to the section using CSS is so that I can use the background-attachment property to make each image fixed which creates a cool parallax effect.

The html structure of the page is basically this:

```
<section id="section-1" class="has-background">
  <div class="section-background">
    <img data-src="url-1">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="section-2" class="has-background">
  <div class="section-background">
    <img data-src="url-2">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="section-3" class="has-background">
  <div class="section-background">
    <img data-src="url-3">
  </div>
</section>
```

The code I have right now doesn't work properly because it takes the first image and applies it as the background image for all the sections. It does give the parallax effect I want, but I need each section to use its own image.

```
var imageUrl = $('.section-background img').attr("data-src");
  $('.has-background').css({'background-image': 'url(' + imageUrl + ')', 'background-size': 'cover', 'background-attachment': 'fixed'});
```

So my question is, how can I create a function that gets the background image from within the section and applies it as the background image using CSS **and** does it for each section that has a background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to run a block of code for each element matched by the selector:

```js
$('.section-background img').each(function () {
    var $targetImg = $(this);    // the current img
    var imgSrc = $targetImg.attr('data-src');
    var $parentDiv = $targetImg.closest('.has-background');

    $parentDiv.css(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has similar logic with my question.

you need to set a **target** where the script/command should be placed.
You may want to use `.next()` and `each()`, or set `data-target="#targetId"` to put the script on a specific element.

here is my post :
[How to correctly write jQuery toggle button that can work individualy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142888/how-to-correctly-write-jquery-toggle-button-that-can-work-individualy/59143161#59143161)